# Как можно округлить число не прибегая к библиотеке cmath?

Tags: c++, c++11

**Вопрос:** на входе имеем дробное число, которое необходимо округлить вниз и вверх. Как можно реализовать подобную вещь в с++? На просторах интернета не нашёл ничего похожего (либо плохо искал)

Comment: (int)(value) и (int)(value + 0.999) ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, ограничимся положительными значениями. Тогда в рамках представимости значений типами (бессмысленно пытаться округлять гугол с половиной...) можно попробовать так:

```
unsigned int Floor(double x)
{
    return unsigned int(x);
}

unsigned int Ceil(double x)
{
    return unsigned int (x) + (Floor(x) != x);
}
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: А отрицательные числа?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Зависит от того, что именно хочется. Как именно трактовать "округление вверх" и "округление вниз". Тут у меня есть определенные сомнения, что именно хочет ТС. Если он напишет точное ТЗ — можно будет посмотреть...